# How to Display ListBox / ListView Column Alignment

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm trying to Display ListBoxes / ListViews as 2 Columns with the first one left aligned and second one right aligned.

I'd think this would be super easy and it probably is, but every time I google it I can't come up with what I need.  I need to display either a listview or listbox (doesn't matter which) with two columns, the first of which is left aligned and second of which is right aligned.

Also will need to know how to populate it. I have tried quite a few different approaches, but can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you have the code you are looking for:

```
With ListView1
    .View = View.Details
    .Columns.Add("Column1")
    .Columns.Add("Column2")
    .Columns(0).TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left
    .Columns(1).TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right
    Dim item As New ListViewItem(New String() {"row1-col1", "row1-col2"})
    .Items.Add(item)
End With
```

Comment: Thanks... I knew it would be easy, but I was going nuts looking for a legit answer

Comment: @user1815207 This control has a somehow-peculiar behaviour and thus misunderstandings are normal. If you don't rely on an ListViewItem, you would have problems; also you have to set the .View to Details, etc.